# Huge memory usage in C++ MCTS algorithm

Tags: c++, heap-memory, monte-carlo-tree-search

I am implementing a Monte Carlo Tree Search algorithm in C++. I create one huge tree at a time  in a for loop, a different one at each iteration. My problem is that each tree is vast and if i create 12000 trees, my program crashes because all available memory in the PC is allocated.
The thing is, that the tree that i create in the iteration 5 for example, is useless in the next iterations, so i would like to free the memory it has allocated. I create each node as `std::make_shared<Node<T, A, E>` where Node is a class that i have created, and the tree as an instance of a class `mcts = MCTS(laneFreeState(state), backpropagation, terminationCheck,scoring)`

Comment: please show the code. If the shared pointer lives in the scope of the loop, no memory should pile up. We cannot help you with code that you do not show. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: At the very least show the data structure for your tree. My first bet would be that you create reference circles of shared pointers (child nodes holding shared pointers to parent nodes who also hold shared pointers to their children) but without code it's impossible to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `std::make_shared` is using `new` to allocate memory on the heap. So when you finish using the tree, just recursively iterate it, deleting the nodes as you go (deepest first, then work backwards).

Comment: What’s the point of using shared pointers then?